# cardano-cli transaction submit example with native assets

Tags: cardano-cli, native-assets, token

I'm having trouble using the cardano-cli to send one tx. I have one address with 9 ADA and 10,000,000 each of two tokens with the same minting policy and I want to send 5,000,000 ADA of each token to a foreign address which has 10 ADA and no tokens.

***For example***

**Address that has the native assets I want to send:**

TxHash: 123456789123465

TxIx: 0

Amount: 9000000 lovelace + 10000000 1234567891234.token1 + 10000000 1234567891234.token2 + TxOutDatumHashNone

**Address which I want to send native assets to:**

TxHash: 123456789123456

TxIx: 0

Amount: 10000000

**What commands/steps exactly** are needed using the cardano-cli from here in order to accomplish sending 5,000,000 of each native token?

Thanks, Myles

Comment: First thing to note, you can only send to an address, not a txhash. Can you also provide what commands you've tried already and what error occurs when doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MY_ADDR=addr_test1qzl6m...
#Send lovelace change to my address
CHANGE_ADDR=$MY_ADDR      
MY_UTXO_IN=123456789123465#0
RECEPIENT_ADDR=addr_test1...

# Build tx
cardano_cli transaction build \
--alonzo-era \
--tx-in $MY_UTXO_IN \
--tx-out $RECEPIENT_ADDR+9000000+"10000000 1234567891234.token1"+"10000000 1234567891234.token2") \
--change-address $CHANGE_ADDR \
--testnet-magic 1097911063 \
--out-file tx.build
```

If you have change in native tokens then you need to add another `--tx-out` to return to your address for example:

```
TOKEN1_CHANGE=1000
TOKEN2_CHNAGE=2000
--tx-out $CHANGE_ADDR+1400000+"$TOKEN1_CHANGE 1234567891234.token1"+"$TOKEN2_CHANGE 1234567891234.token2"
```

Sign and submit

```
# Sign tx
echo "Sign Tx ..."
cardano_cli transaction sign \
--signing-key-file my_payment.skey \
--tx-body-file tx.build \
--out-file tx.sign
echo "Done."

# Submit tx
echo "Submiting Tx ..."
cardano-cli transaction submit --testnet-magic 1097911063 --tx-file tx.sign
```

Here you can find various examples for sending token and other stuff https://github.com/invictusappscom/cardano-terminal-wallet especially this script https://github.com/invictusappscom/cardano-terminal-wallet/blob/master/send-token.sh